# Need help with animation on JavaScript without jQuery

Tags: javascript

I have got a div object for example (Simple Image), and I need my picture to move to right and left and backward without any frame and border. My picture will collide with end  (right side of my page) and move backward to left and then action with right side too. This will be only on JavaScript.

**Edit:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script> 
function dvig () { 
    var xx = 50; 
    var corner_left=200 +'px'; 
    var corner_right=100 +'px'; 
    var move; var move2; 
    var dv=document.getElementById("adam"); 
    if(dv.style.left<=corner_right) { 
        move=1; 
        move2=1; 
    } 
    if(dv.style.left>=corner_left) {
        move2=0; 
        move=0; 
    } 
    if(move=1) { 
        dv.style.left=parseInt(document.getElementById("adam").style.left)+xx; 
    } 
    if (move2=0) { 
        move=0; 
        dv.style.left=parseInt(document.getElementById("adam").style.left)-xx; 
    } 
} 
function chustro() { 
    setInterval("dvig()", 100); 
} 
</script> 
</head>
<body onload="chustro()">
    <img id="adam" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 100px; width: 40px; height: 40px; background-color: red">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like a homework to me. Can you please give a good reason for not using an existing library?

Comment: Mr. Dat Chu i need only in javascript, i am learning javascript, and when i did this task i have got a mistake, i will post the code that i have written, but i have a problem with borders of the page

Comment: <html><head>
<script>
function dvig ()
{
var xx = 50;
var corner_left=200 +'px';
var corner_right=100 +'px';
var move;
var move2;

var dv=document.getElementById("adam");

if(dv.style.left<=corner_right)
{
move=1;
move2=1;
}
if(dv.style.left>=corner_left)
{
move2=0;
move=0;
}


if(move=1)
{
dv.style.left=parseInt(document.getElementById("adam").style.left)+xx;
}
if (move2=0)
{
move=0;
dv.style.left=parseInt(document.getElementById("adam").style.left)-xx;
}
}


function chustro()
{
setInterval("dvig()", 100);
}
</script>
</head>

Comment: <body onload="chustro()">
<img id="adam" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 100px;
                       width: 40px; height: 40px; background-color: red">
</body></html>

Comment: I have a mistake's here please help me with the solution

Comment: @Adam: Always edit your question directly. Don't post additions to the comments.

Comment: @Adam - once answered, leave the question as it was so others can see in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your going to have to setup a iterative process that runs every X milliseconds. Each time its run you have to update the div's position a bit and check if it hits a side and reverse direction.

```
function doWork{
    // move current direction a little

    // check if past the left edge and change directions

    // check if past the right edge and change direction
}

setInterval(doWork, 10);
```

**Update:**

Based on your code, check this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/HT9A4/

Comment: Mr. Justin can you to look at my javascript code and to write what the problem?